# httpd.conf configuration issue

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I'm currently migrating a bunch of websites to amazon ec2 (running on the Amazon Linux AMI), and am having difficulties getting Apache's VirtualHost configuration to work.

Here's what my httpd.conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/example.com/

    <Directory /home/sites/example.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.access.log combined


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName blog.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/sites/blog.example.com/

        <Directory /home/sites/blog.example.com>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/blog.example.com.error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/blog.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the result of httpd -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
         port 80 namevhost blog.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1029)
Syntax OK
```

However, if I attempt to go to blog.example.com, I get a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED response.

If I change the first VirtualHost definition to blog.example.com, I can load the blog.example.com site, so both sites are working, leading me to suspect I either have configured something wrong in VirtualHost, or on the end of my domain registrar.

Comment: Your problem is likely DNS. Do you have a record for blog.example.com?

Comment: So I should have an A record for example.com and blog.example.com, both going to the same IP, right? That still isn't working for me.

Comment: Ah, it was simply an issue of order, the domain prefix versions of the site need to come before example.com.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had the example.com domain before the blog.example.com domain, meaning everything just went to example.com. Order matters!